# What is the source for ijaab (offering) and qabul (acceptance) in marriage?

Tags: nikah, sunni, islamic-basis

[*Kindly note that I'm only looking for the sunni view*]

During a nikah, I know with evidences that the khutbah (sermon) is done with certain verses from the Qur'aan and hadeeth.

But I often find that the one who conducts the marriage reads out a **formula speech** known as **ijab and qabool** (i.e. offering and acceptance). However, I find it difficult to find a single *hadeeth* where this is done during a nikah. I witness where the conductor of the marriage holds the hand of the groom and the bride's walee and gets them to repeat some words.

Can someone please help me find the source for this action?

Comment: It might be a cultural thing...

Comment: @goto In whose culture? Do you find it in your country? And if it's not from the authentic sources, wouldn't it be bid'ah since nikah is an act of ibaadah?

Comment: On my marriage, there was khutba-e-nikkah (in arabic) and a small speech and dua in local language. Noone held my hand during the khutba. I think khutba is a Sunnah, so it can not be omitted.

Comment: @goto Yes, the Khutbah is from the sunnah. It must NOT be omitted. But I don't know why all those additions have come in and if one does not do them, people think that something is wrong... BTW, I'm glad your nikah went off like that.

Comment: What is the need of nikah tag while we are already having marriage tag?

Comment: @Muslim some (or perhaps many - Allaahu a'lam) don't know to relate the words marriage, wedding, nikah, engagement, registration. And some people may search it differently. BTW, I think this should be a discussion on meta.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum,

I myself also never came across any such hadith, but just heard from the Fiqh hanafi that they must do ijaab o qubool in loud voice in front of everyone.

The reason for it (in my personal opinion) might be that, as according to Sunnah way of nikah, both parties have to mutually agree on marriage, that they accept it. So Acceptance is one of the major part of nikah. So obviously they have to do Ijab o quboool atleast for a fixed number of time infront of everyone.

And Allah knows the best.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any hadith. It is more of a culture thing. There are a few requirements for Marriage in Islam:

- Acceptance of both parties and a knowledge of the parties to each other.
- A presence of a figure head (Father, Brother, Son, Imam, Judge, etc..)
- Two witnesses

If those conditions are met, the way the marriage occurs (in Masjid, in home, in city hall, etc..) it is valid inshala. For example, If you live in NYC and you go to City Hall and request a marriage contract, you are met with the above requirements and thus your marriage is legal and Islamic at the same time - There is no need to go to the Masjid and perform a separate ceremony, unless you wish for it.

Answer (score -2):

Ejaab  qaboob and 2 witnesses are main part of nikah and khutba is sunnat means doing khutba is good . These three things are in hadees

Comment: This answer Needs more meat (see [answer).

Answer (score -3):

A Nikkah consists of the following 4:

1.Ejaab (an offer) from the bride's father or wali and Qabool (acceptance) from the groom
2. 2 male, sane, muslim witnesses - one from each side.
3. The Mahr which is a free gift to the bride from the groom And 
4. The marriage khutbah or the sermon must be delivered by the Imam reminding them of their responsibilities to each other as husband and wife.